# More efficient way to create dataframe of top n values - python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe of categories that I need to clean up by limiting the values to the top n categories. Any value that isn't in the top n categories, should be binned under 0 (or "other").

I tried the code below, which loops through each row of a column, then through each column in a dataframe to check if the value in that position is found in that column's top n value_counts. If yes, then it keeps the value, if not then replaces with 0.

This implementation technically works, but when the number of rows is large, it takes too long to run. What is the quicker way of accomplishing this in pandas/numpy?

```
z = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,4,size=(100000, 4)))
x=pd.DataFrame()    
n=10
for j in z:
    for i in z[j].index:     
        if z.at[i,j] in z[j].value_counts().head(n).index.tolist():
            x.at[i,j] = z.at[i,j]
        else:
            x.at[i,j]= 0
print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) for loop columns with custom function with [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) for top values and [`where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for boolean mask for replacing:

```
def f(x):
    y = x.value_counts().head(n).index
    return x.where(x.isin(y), 0)

print (z.apply(f))
```

What is same as:

```
print (z.apply(lambda x: x.where(x.isin(x.value_counts().head(n).index), 0)))
```

Sample:

```
#N =100000
N = 10
np.random.seed(123)
z = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,4,size=(N, 4)))
print (z)
   0  1  2  3
0  3  2  3  3
1  1  3  3  2
2  3  2  3  2
3  1  2  3  2
4  1  3  1  2
5  3  2  1  1
6  1  1  2  3
7  1  3  1  1
8  2  1  2  1
9  1  1  3  2
```

---

```
x=pd.DataFrame()    
n=2
for j in z:
    for i in z[j].index:     
        if z.at[i,j] in z[j].value_counts().head(n).index.tolist():
            x.at[i,j] = z.at[i,j]
        else:
            x.at[i,j]= 0
print(x) 
     0    1    2    3
0  3.0  2.0  3.0  0.0
1  1.0  3.0  3.0  2.0
2  3.0  2.0  3.0  2.0
3  1.0  2.0  3.0  2.0
4  1.0  3.0  1.0  2.0
5  3.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
6  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
7  1.0  3.0  1.0  1.0
8  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0
9  1.0  0.0  3.0  2.0
```

---

```
print (z.apply(lambda x: x.where(x.isin(x.value_counts().head(n).index), 0)))
   0  1  2  3
0  3  2  3  0
1  1  3  3  2
2  3  2  3  2
3  1  2  3  2
4  1  3  1  2
5  3  2  1  1
6  1  0  0  0
7  1  3  1  1
8  0  0  0  1
9  1  0  3  2
```

Similar solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
print (z.apply(lambda x: np.where(x.isin(x.value_counts().head(n).index), x, 0)))
   0  1  2  3
0  3  2  3  0
1  1  3  3  2
2  3  2  3  2
3  1  2  3  2
4  1  3  1  2
5  3  2  1  1
6  1  0  0  0
7  1  3  1  1
8  0  0  0  1
9  1  0  3  2
```